# Why we need jQuery click event inside callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Hi I am using a jquery callback function to check the state of the checkbox. I am using the following code but i cant understand why we need a click event one more time inside the callback.  After including the code it works fine. Can anyone tell me the mechanism for this with illustration really helps.  Thanks in advance.

```
 function notify() {
       if (jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
           ...
       } else {
        ....
       }
          jQuery("#dummy").on("click", notify); // Why i need this to do it again
          //Is it will work like recursive function
     }

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#dummy").on("click",notify); //This is my callback
   });
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason. Maybe the reason is related to the code you omitted.

Comment: Your premise is wrong; you *don't* need to do this again. This will in fact run the click handler code twice, then three times, then four times, etc.

Comment: "*After including the code it works fine*" - does it also work fine if you also remove the one inside `notify()`?

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
jQuery("#dummy").on("click", notify);
```

really shouldn't be in the callback. BTW, it does not click a button, it registers another 'click' listener. And not only one but one extra listener each time you click.

First click, one listener is called and calls 'notify'. That adds a second one.

Second click, two listners are called, both add another one which totals up to 4. Next click it's 8, then 16, ... After a few clicks your system should really slow down.

So, delete that one inside the notify method.

Comment: My scenario is this I have single check box, two radio buttons and one submit button. Now am  checked the checkbox with state of checkbox.  Am adding attribute checked to the radio_button_2. After all am submitting it the Ajax request done. After Ajax response. Am unchecked the checkbox and trying to add attribute checked to radio_button_1 but am not able to maintain the state of checkbox and radio button. For this am using the above code, please suggest any good solution for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

> Why we need jQuery click event inside callback

You *would* (could) do this if, and only if, the bits you removed `...` *replaces* `#dummy` with some new HTML.

Then the original click event would be removed (as the element it refers to would no longer exist) - so you need to add the event handler for the new HTML.

This scenario would be better served using event delegation.

---

An alternative is if you change `.on` to `.one` to ensure it's only clicked once at a time (eg if the click event handler does some ajax and you don't want the user to click it again while it's saving the existing data (for example)).

You then re-add the .one event when your processing has finished.

Given the (limited) code provided, this doesn't appear to be the scenario in your question (as there's no ajax to "wait for").  It would also be better if there was visual updates on the button (eg graying out).